# JavaScript. Tell me why I can't change an element at index i in an array at index j

Tags: javascript

This doesn't work, and it is beyond me. Could this be a bug in my browser? Using Chrome Version 43.0.2357.81 m

```
var array = ['test', 'this'];

array[0][0] = 'T';

console.log(array);

// expected result ["Test", "this"];
// actual result ["test", "this"]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hdh3v5vx/

This also doesn't work.

```
array.forEach(function(value, index, a) {
    a[index][0] = value[0].toUpperCase();
});
```

Comment: You can't modify a _String_ like this, it's a primitive

Comment: What do you want to do? Capitalize the first character?

Comment: I'm looking for a specific reason why this doesn't work. If anyone can provide me an excerpt from the standard, that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

We are unable to address an index of a string. However, you could replace the whole string (array[0] = 'Test') or do the following:

```
var firstString = array[0].split('');
firstString[0] = 'T';
array[0] = firstString.join('');
```

If you're looking to capitalize the first letter of different words, I recommend writing a helper function to do that.

Comment: Yeah, this isn't one of the 'good' parts. :) But a helper function may be a decent way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify a *String* like this, it's a primitive

> If anyone can provide me an excerpt from the standard, that would be great.

The logic is described in [**§8.7.2** of the ES5 spec](http://es5.github.io/#x8.7.2), specfically 4.a.

> If `HasPrimitiveBase(V)` is `false`, then let put be the `[[Put]]` internal method of base, otherwise let put be the special `[[Put]]` internal method defined below.

and then the note of the special `[[Put]]` (as *`HasPrimitiveBase(V)` returns `true` if the base value is a Boolean, String or Number.*)

> The object that may be created in step 1 is not accessible outside of the above method

i.e. by setting you create a new object which has a property set, but this object is not the *String* you have the reference to